# Deciphering bounding box of private API

Tags: coordinate-system

I'm using an undocumented private API to grab some tiles. But it's using a strange coordinate system.

The area covered is

`-77.318467, 44.148949, -77.297040, 44.133303`

however the APIs bounding box is

`-8607208.443178354, 5485854.929815598, -8604638.248102197, 5489027.066489516`

Is there a name for this system? And is there a simple way to convert lat/lng to this coordinate system?

Comment: There could be a lot of names for this. Essentially, it's probably a projected coordinate system. People might be able to offer guesses based on the published extent. My question is: given that you seem to know the area covered already, how do you know that?

Comment: I looked up the same area on google maps and matched the bounding area, so it's close but not 100%